# SQL update with CASE and WHERE conditions

Tags: sql, database, sql-update, clickhouse

I want to update some values (column "value") in the table with new values, with the condition that the names I need match in the "name" column.

Also I want to make the values update only in a limited range of time. But when I run my query I get an error. Please could someone help me with my SQL query ?

(Also on the real data here is many names that i want to update ~ 55-70 pieces and about 300 names that i don't want to update , so this is why i want to use CAST)

Current data in table:

```
time                    name    value
----------------------------------------
2023-07-06 06:01:00.001 apple   0
2023-07-06 10:00:00.001 apple   0.2
2023-07-06 10:00:01.051 banana  1
2023-07-06 10:00:01.651 orange  0.5
2023-07-06 10:00:01.690 orange  0.5
2023-07-06 10:00:02.772 apple   0.1
2023-07-06 10:00:03.002 apple   0.2
2023-07-06 10:00:03.111 banana  3
2023-07-06 10:00:03.830 orange  5.5
2023-07-06 10:00:03.891 orange  6.5
2023-07-06 10:00:04.330 orange  3.5
2023-07-06 10:00:05.311 orange  3.2
2023-07-06 10:00:05.801 apple   0.7
2023-07-06 10:00:05.951 apple   0.2
2023-07-06 10:00:06.091 apple   0.1
2023-07-07 10:00:01.051 banana  1
```

Data that i want receive after update:

```
time                    name    value
----------------------------------------
2023-07-06 06:01:00.001 apple   0
2023-07-06 10:00:00.001 apple   0.3
2023-07-06 10:00:01.051 banana  6
2023-07-06 10:00:01.651 orange  0.5
2023-07-06 10:00:01.690 orange  0.5
2023-07-06 10:00:02.772 apple   0.2
2023-07-06 10:00:03.002 apple   0.3
2023-07-06 10:00:03.111 banana  8
2023-07-06 10:00:03.830 orange  5.5
2023-07-06 10:00:03.891 orange  6.5
2023-07-06 10:00:04.330 orange  3.5
2023-07-06 10:00:05.311 orange  3.2
2023-07-06 10:00:05.801 apple   0.8
2023-07-06 10:00:05.951 apple   0.3
2023-07-06 10:00:06.091 apple   0.2
2023-07-07 10:00:01.051 banana  1
```

My  SQL Update query:

```
UPDATE stage.log
SET value = CASE 
    WHEN name='banana'   THEN value -(-5)
    WHEN name='apple'    THEN value -(-0.1)
END
FROM stage.log
WHERE  time >= '2023-07-09 07:01:11.784'
AND    time <= '2023-07-09 07:01:11.998'
AND bt_run_no = 0
AND name in ('banana','apple')
```

ERROR:

```
SQL Error [62] [07000]: Code: 62. DB::Exception: Syntax error: failed at position 191 ('FROM') (line 5, col 1): FROM stage.log
WHERE  time >= '2023-07-09 07:01:11.784'
AND    time <= '2023-07-09 07:01:11.998'
AND bt_run_no = 0
AND name in . Expected one of: OR, AND, BETWEEN, NOT BETWEEN, LIKE, ILIKE, NOT LIKE, NOT ILIKE, REGEXP, IN, NOT IN, GLOBAL IN, GLOBAL NOT IN, MOD, DIV, IS NULL, IS NOT NULL, token, Comma, IN PARTITION, WHERE. (SYNTAX_ERROR) (version 23.3.2.37 (official build))
```

Comment: What type is `time`? You can convert it to DateTime and compare that way

Comment: it's a DateTime64

Answer (score 1):

According to [the official documentation](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/guides/developer/mutations) Use the `ALTER TABLE...UPDATE` command to update rows in a table :

```
ALTER TABLE log
UPDATE value = CASE 
    WHEN name='banana' THEN value -(-5)
    WHEN name='apple'  THEN value -(-0.1)
END
WHERE  time >= '2023-07-09 07:01:11.784'
AND    time <= '2023-07-09 07:01:11.998'
AND bt_run_no = 0
AND name in ('banana','apple');
```